# Proof, possibly involving distribution of the disjunction over biconditionals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

*Title does not display the proof because the formula would break the character limit.*

Presently working on proving the following identity:

$(\lnot P \lor Q)\land(\lnot Q \lor R) \equiv (\lnot P \lor R) \land[(P \leftrightarrow Q) \lor (R \leftrightarrow Q)]$

I tried applying the distributivity of the disjunction over the two biconditional statements on the RHS hoping it would lead somewhere, but after a lot of writing it seemed I'd only needlessly complicated the problem. I'm working off the assumption that most of the work needs to be done to the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

The following proof uses the law of the excluded middle to reach the goal:

[image]

The overall strategy of the first part was to use the law of the excluded middle on $Q \lor \lnot Q$ to derive the right hand side of the equivalence from the left hand side.

[image]

[image]

Again for the second part the law of the excluded middle on $Q \lor \lnot Q$ was used as the main strategy to derive the left hand side from the right hand side.

The proof concludes with the biconditional introduction.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/